# Adding a request option in Customized Google Map where users can request Admin to see to other users' phone number

Tags: google-maps, gmail-api, google-sheets-query

I'm building a **customized google map** for my high school network of students, teachers, and Alumni.

I have collected the user information using google forms. I've implemented them to make a customized google map.
[Map1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2o4r.jpg)

[Map2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hDLI.jpg)

I have all the phone numbers but I don't want to make them public. Instead, I want to insert a custom link in the description(image 2) will be titled as "Request to see phone number". If a user(let, A) clicks in it to see other users'(let, B) phone number then an email will be sent to B to confirm if he wants to give permission to show his phone number to A. If he gives permission B will get an email with the phone number of A collected from "Phone Number" column of the spreadsheet.
**How can I complete this task ?? Is there any proper resource of information for this ?? Please help.**

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create an application where you can save user profiles and responses into a database. Of course, this application should have a login/logout capability for privacy and security concerns. All **[Personally Identifiable Information (PII)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data)** should not be exposed to the public as it may cause harm or discomfort to someone.

Once the user is logged in, he can now view the map and click the markers he desired. The **[Google Maps Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)** will show a **[Google Maps Infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)** and represent each user's location on the map and some information wherein the **phone numbers** are redacted.

If the user clicks the "Request to see phone number", the person who owns or manages that phone number will be notified via email and will now be able to respond back. These transactions should be saved in a database for monitoring purposes. Below are some of the table schemas you can use for this kind of application:

**Table name: user_profiles**

Fields:

- ID
- firstname
- middle_name
- last_name
- email_address
- user_name
- password
- batch
- district
- thana_upazilla
- union_village_Street
- current_position
- phone_number

**Table name: user_requests**

Fields:

- ID
- requestor_profile_id (relative with Table: user_profile.ID)
- full_name
- email_address
- requested_profile_id (relative with Table: user_profile.ID)
- approve (value: yes/no)
- date_requested
- date_approved_or_denied

The user's address should be **[Geocoded](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)** so it can be plotted to the map. Each location will now represent a marker.

I would advise to use **[Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)** for the map, **[PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/)** and **[MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)** for the database.

I am sure that your appliation will be useful to your students/teachers and alumnis.